# importing all functions and constants from another jsx file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to create a jsx file that will have several functions/constants that I will like to use in other jsx files. How can I do to import all those functions and constants from that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write that function as 'export function funcName() { ...code }' and import it as '@import { funcName } from 'name of folder  with index.jsx file ' '
Or '@import * as common from '/way'
And then u should get your const as common.varname

Comment: `@import` is not valid JavaScript.